# Actively display elapsed time using watch in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that's used to run some programs to collect data from a system, and at the end of the script is a watch that displays the size of the output file at a refresh rate of 1s.
I was attempting to make it also display how long the script had been running, using $SECONDS, but it appears that putting $SECONDS into watch reads $SECONDS from when the watch started.

Is there a better way to do this, or a way to make $SECONDS work in this context?

The portions of code that are relevant, with an attempt to generalize it:

```
convertsecs() { #Function used to convert seconds into HH:MM:SS
    ((h=${1}/3600))
    ((m=(${1}%3600)/60))
    ((s=${1}%60))
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s
}

SECONDS=0 #Start counting from this point
watch -n 1 "<pipeline stuff> | awk '{print \"some stuff here\",\"Time elapsed: \",\"$(convertsecs $SECONDS)\"}'"
```

Edit:
I did confirm that the problem is that watch takes $SECONDS as its value and then keeps that value for the duration of its watch, so the question at this point is what's a better way to do this, or a way that works
Example of what I mean:
`SECONDS=0
watch -n 1 "echo $SECONDS"`
results in
`Every 1.0s: echo 0
0`

Comment: Did you try escaping the dollar sign: `\$SECONDS`

Comment: That results in `Time elapsed:  $SECONDS` as the output
As it is now, it displays $SECONDS converted to the HH:MM:SS format, but it never goes up, it stays as whatever it was when it went in.
for example, if you add `sleep 3` after `SECONDS=0` then the output would be `Time elapsed: 00:00:03` instead of `Time elapsed: 00:00:00`

Comment: I understand the problem and why it occurs with your current approach (the text `$SECONDS` is expanded by bash on the command line and it's current value is passed to `watch`, so of course it never changes). Unfortunately I don't have access to a linux machine right now and I don't know how `watch` works internally. What does this command do: `watch -n 1 "echo \$SECONDS"`

Comment: Is that `$SECONDS` a magic variable managed by `watch`? Otherwise how is it incremented?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux `SECONDS` is a "magic variable" in bash.

Comment: @ooga But, AFAIK, `watch` launch a `sh` -- not `bash`. Is it defined too in that case? Even so, as `watch` spawn a new shell each time it runs the command, `$SECONDS` will always be `0` in the currently running shell. I guess.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I don't know and I can't test it at the moment. Could you try running `watch -n 1 "echo \$SECONDS"` to see what the result is? I think you're probably right. Actually, don't bother since you're obviously correct for that example. But I think it still might work for the OP's example.

Comment: @ooga ;) as a matter of fact, I've tested before posting my previous comment: `watch -n 1 'echo XX${SECONDS}YY'` displays `XXYY`. And `watch ps` actually show than `watch` forks and launch a new shell (`sh`) to execute the command each time.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux I figured you probably did!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a basic script doing what you want, I presume:

```
#!/bin/bash

convertsecs() { #Function used to convert seconds into HH:MM:SS
    ((h=${1}/3600))
    ((m=(${1}%3600)/60))
    ((s=${1}%60))
    printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" $h $m $s
}
typeset -fx convertsecs # export to sub-shells
                        # maybe this is implicit with your version of Bash

NOW=$(exec date +%s)

cmd() {
    echo it"'"s fact of life than shell   # Replace by *your*
    echo quoting can be a '"nightmare"'   # actual commands
}
typeset -fx cmd

watch -n 1 \
    'bash -c '"'"'cat <(cmd) \
                      <(echo Elapsed $(convertsecs $(($(exec date +%s) - '$NOW'))))'"'"
```

The key issue is to properly quote the command passed to watch. In addition, I've exported the *function* `convertsecs` so it is available in sub-shells.

Notice how I wrap the "user commands" in a function. That way, I don't have to worry about proper quoting of those commands when passed as an argument to `watch`.

Moreover, here I used `cat` with process substitution to append the line "Elapsed ..." after the output of my main command. I made that choice to clearly separate the "useful stuff" (`cmd`) from the "cosmetic stuff" (`Elapsed ...`).

Comment: So this seems like it would work to me, and is formatted in the way I wanted and everything
I've tried implementing it and it's giving me 
`,: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
,: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`
Note that there is a "`" in there that is taken by the comment
I feel like I'm doing something wrong, but I can't see it. Here's my line:
`watch -n 1 'bash -c '"'"'cat <('"$CMD"') <(echo Elapsed $(convertsecs $(($( date +%s ) - '$NOW'))))'"'"`
I removed the line breaks, and I changed some other things in testing (removed exec)
I did use typeset

Comment: @sumbuddy31 I can't say for sure, but this is probably because of some of your commands (`$CMD`) containing quotes. You should have to protect them like I've done when calling `watch` itself. This can easely become a nightmare. So **instead** I suggest you to wrap your commands in a shell _function_. It would be much more clear, easier to maintain and you will escape from the "quoting hell". I've modified my answer to show you how to proceed.

Comment: Had to fiddle a whole bunch of stuff, but I got it to work.
Thanks for getting me on the right track!

Comment: I get `bash: cmd: command not found` and `bash: convertsecs: command not found`.